# "Copy from active" doesn't work as expected

Tags: objects, physics, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

I am trying to apply Physics effects to cubes I have created by using the "copy from Active" command.

So this cube has Collision, Soft Body and Rigid Body settings:

[image: physics settings]

I selected my target objects (all the cubes except the ones on the front row) with *Border Select* (<kbd>B</kbd>) in *Object Mode*, then my source object via (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>):

[image: all cubes selected]

Then "copy from active":

[image: copy from active]

And then I think it doesn't work, because when I click on just one of these cubes, they only have Rigid Body enabled, not Collision or Soft Body:

[image: physics settings]

And indeed, they behave very differently than the front row:

[image: animated gif of the cubes behaving differently]

So, I'm trying to understand why "Copy from Active" didn't copy everything from active - if that's normal or if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command **Copy from Active** belongs to the Rigid Body Tools panel, which is a subcategory of the Physics Tab:

[image]

As stated by the Hint, Copy from active is just referring to the

> Rigid Body settings

and not to the whole physics settings. Rigid body physics is treated in a different way.

---

You can copy the other physics settings from the active object of the selection by **Making Links** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and choosing the **Modifiers** option.

Comment: Thank you! I selected the target objects/cubes first, then one on the front, and clicked on Making Links -> Modifiers but the target objects now have 2 physics settings (soft Body and Rigid Body) instead of three (Collision was left out). I also realized the origin wasn't at the center of geometry for the back cubes, but that's another thing...

Answer (score 0):

in Blender 2.8 you need to select all the cubes, shift select the cube with the Rigid Body physics, select in Object Mode: Object/Rigid Body/Copy from Active.

With all cubes selected, then select: Object/Set Origin/Origin to Geometry